# Алгоритм игры Ним за компьютер

Tags: алгоритм, python-3.6

> Древняя и почтенная игра Ним имеет такие правила: имеется несколько куч камней. Каждый игрок в свой ход может забрать из любой кучи любое (ненулевое) количество камней. Выигрывает тот, кто забрал последний камень из последней кучи. 
>   Игра ним с двумя кучами камней, начальное количество камней в кучах задаёт пользователь.
>
> Компьютер (ИИ) играет против пользователя и ходит первым. В каждый ход можно взять сколько угодно камней из любой одной кучи. При этом нужно предусмотреть ситуацию, когда пользователь не сразу вводит корректное количество камней, которые он забирает.
>
> Выигрывает забравший последний камень, и при окончании игры нужно объявить победителя.

Эту задачу я решил с помощью рандома, но такое решение у меня не приняли. Мне нужно создать какой-либо алгоритм для ИИ, чтобы он побеждал пользователя.

```
import random
count = int(input('Исходное кол-во камней в первой куче: '))
count2 = int(input('Исходное кол-во камней во второй куче: '))
while count >= 0 or count2 >= 0:
    if count == 0 and count2 == 0:
        break
    else:
        if (count != 0 and count2 != 0 or count == 0 and count2 != 0 or
            count != 0 and count2 == 0):      
            digit = random.randint(1, 10)
            if count == 0:
                pile = 2
            elif count2 == 0:
                pile = 1
            else:
                pile = random.randint(1, 2)
            count_comp = count
            if pile == 1:
                count_pile = count
                count -= digit
                if count <= 0:
                    digit = count_pile
                    count = 0
            elif pile == 2:
                count2_pile = count
                count2 -= digit
                if count2 <= 0:
                    digit = count2_pile
                    count2 = 0
            if count <= 0 and count2 <= 0:
                print('Компьютер забрал', count_comp, 'камней. Осталось', 
                      '0')
                print('Компьютер победил!')
                break
            else:
                print('Компьютер забрал', digit, 'камней из', pile, 
                      'кучи.Осталось', count, count2)
                takes = int(input('Выберите кол-во камней: '))
                your_pile = int(input('Выберите кучу: '))
                if your_pile == 1:
                    count -= takes
                    print('Юзер забрал', takes, 'камней из', your_pile,
                          'кучи.Осталось', count, count2)
                elif your_pile == 2:
                    count2 -= takes                              
                    print('Юзер забрал', takes, 'камней из', your_pile,
                          'кучи.Осталось', count, count2)    
                if count <= 0 and count2 <= 0:
                    print('Юзер забрал', takes, 'камней. Осталось',
                          '0', '0')
                    print('Юзер победил!')
                    break
```

Answer (score 1):

Ним с двумя кучами имеет очень простую выигрышную стратегию - нужно взять из большей кучи столько камней, чтобы кучи стали равными.

Это следствие общей стратегии с ксором.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению на то что бы написать ответ в комментарии рейтинга моловато. Можете расценивать это как комментарий.

гуглим: `Nim game 100% algorithm`, `NIM minimax algorithm`

[Поиск с гитхаба](https://github.com/search?l=Python&q=nim%20game&type=Repositories)

Сам код не смотрел, оставлю это вам, но вот как [пример](https://github.com/akawashiro/NimmtAI) того, что было найденно за пол минуты

Полезные на мой взгляд ссылки:

https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs97si/05-combinatorial-games.pdf

[http://www.cis.umassd.edu/~ivalova/Spring08/cis412/Old/Game_last.pdf](http://www.cis.umassd.edu/%7Eivalova/Spring08/cis412/Old/Game_last.pdf)

http://eprints.fri.uni-lj.si/2088/

Возможно мой "ответ" не содержит решение. Так что прошу расценивать его как комментарий. Если найдете там ответ, напишите об этом здесь.

Comment: Возможно, стоило потратить эти усилия в другом вопросе и написать полноценный ответ, получив тем самым баллы для открытия возможности комментирования :)